# Exporting data which includes rule as number only and use lhs as label

Tags: list-manipulation, export, rule

I use `listD1 = Table[FindRoot[(*my eqns depending on k*), {k, conc}]` to get a list of solutions for the different values of `conc = {0.03, 0.06, 0.1, 0.4, 1, 3}`. `listD1` has the form

```
{{s1 -> 0.000405499, s2 -> 0.000265293, s3 -> 0.000194383, V1 -> 0.019469, V2 -> 0.00823285, V0 -> 0.0366434, V3 -> 0., eef -> 0.715569}, 
{s1 -> 0.000974929, s2 -> 0.000464154, s3 -> 0.000291268, V1 -> 0.0319949, V2 -> 0.0123363, V0 -> 0.0732868, V3 -> 0., eef -> 0.704852}, 
{s1 -> 0.00186423, s2 -> 0.000654623, s3 -> 0.000365062, V1 -> 0.0431875, V2 -> 0.0154618, V0 -> 0.122145, V3 -> 0., eef -> 0.698868}, 
{s1 -> 0.00972514, s2 -> 0.00127244, s3 -> 0.000538089, V1 -> 0.0766826, V2 -> 0.0227901, V0 -> 0.488579, V3 -> 0., eef -> 0.688587}, 
{s1 -> 0.0182276, s2 -> 0.00154438, s3 -> 0.000595658, V1 -> 0.0906385, V2 -> 0.0252284, V0 -> 0.862647, V3 -> 0., eef -> 0.685893}, 
{s1 -> 0.0194252, s2 -> 0.00157279, s3 -> 0.000601234, V1 -> 0.0920781, V2 -> 0.0254645, V0 -> 0.914809, V3 -> 0., eef -> 0.685646}}
```

I tried to export `listD1` as `Export["file.txt", Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[listD1], conc]], "CSV"]` which gives me in principle the right output but contains the `s1->` etc. Is there an option to export without the  `s1->`  but instead use it in the first row as label?

the output should be e.g.

```
conc, s1, s2, s3, .....
0.03, 0.000405499,  0.000265293, 0.000194383
0.06, 0.000974929,  0.000464154, 0.000291268
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
labels = Prepend[listD1[[1, All, 1]], "conc"];
data = Transpose@Prepend[Transpose[listD1[[All, All, 2]]], conc];
Export["~/Desktop/file.txt", Join[{labels}, data], "CSV"]
```

Comment: This means that the rule `s1 -> 244` is also treated as a table like `{s1,244}`?

Comment: @user2758804 I'm not sure I get what you're saying, but `[[...]]` (`Part`) can be used on any expression not just lists, if that's where the confusion is.

Comment: @user2758804 Maybe have a look at `FullForm[s1 -> 244]`.